# QGIS API documentation in French?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, references, french

I am looking for a document which explains what the API of QGIS is, with examples of this API but in French.

Answer (score 1):

The closes there is is the French translation of the PyQGIS Cookbook http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/fr/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

The main API docs are in English and I don't expect anyone is going to translate those.